# Rails 4 parsing xml and inserting into postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, postgresql, xml-parsing

As i am changing my databse structure in my rails project, i need the existing data in new db structure.I generated the xml of one of my model How to insert those xml data into database.
The xml which i am generating is

localhost:3000/list/division_makes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <email>1410263233@nabthat.com</email>
        <role>dealer</role>
        <divisions>
            <division_name>BMW</division_name>
            <division_id>200000081</division_id>
        </divisions>
        <bids></bids>
        <counter_bids></counter_bids>
    </user>
    <user>
        <email>1410263236@nabthat.com</email>
        <role>dealer</role>
        <divisions>
            <division_name>Volvo</division_name>   
            <division_id>200010382</division_id>
        </divisions>
        <bids></bids>
        <counter_bids></counter_bids>
    </user>
</users>
```

Comment: You have to try solve it by yourself, and when you get errors - ask us.

Answer (score 4):

add to gemfile `gem 'blockspring'`

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'json'
  require 'blockspring'
  def self.foo(xml_string)
    json_obj = Blockspring.runParsed("xml-to-json", 
     { "my_xml" => xml_string }).params["converted"] 
    f = Foo.new
    f.name = json_obj['note']['to']
    f.save
  end
end
xml_string = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<note>\n\t<to>Tove</to>\n\t<from>Jani</from>\n\t<heading>Reminder</heading>\n\t<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\n</note>"
Foo.foo(xml_string)
```

It is just an example, if you add your code - we can help you better.